# Using C# to edit text within a binary file

Tags: c#

I have a binary file (i.e., it contains bytes with values between 0x00 and 0xFF). There are also ASCII strings in the file (e.g., "Hello World") that I want to find and edit using Regex. I then need to write out the edited file so that it's exactly the same as the old one but with my ASCII edits having been performed.  How?

```
        byte[] inbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(wfile);
        string instring = utf8.GetString(inbytes);
        // use Regex to find/replace some text within instring
        byte[] outbytes = utf8.GetBytes(instring);
        File.WriteAllBytes(outfile, outbytes);
```

Even if I don't do any edits, the output file is different from the input file.  What's going on, and how can I do what I want?

---

EDIT: Ok, I'm trying to use the offered suggestion and am having trouble understanding how to actually implement it.  Here's my sample code:

```
        string infile = @"C:\temp\in.dat";
        string outfile = @"C:\temp\out.dat";
        Regex re = new Regex(@"H[a-z]+ W[a-z]+");  // looking for "Hello World"
        byte[] inbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(infile);
        string instring = new SoapHexBinary(inbytes).ToString();
        Match match = re.Match(instring);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            // do work on 'instring'
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(outfile, SoapHexBinary.Parse(instring).Value);
```

Obviously, I know I'll not get a match doing it that way, but if I convert my Regex to a string (or whatever), then I can't use Match, etc.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You haven't stated how the output varies from the input, but if there is binary data in it, I would imagine the output varies considerably.  You can't convert a binary file to UTF8 and expect the binary data to pass through unscathed.

Comment: Edit a binary file with regex? No don't try to do it.

Comment: So all you're asking is how to read a binary file as text, change it, and save it to disk, right? Regex is irrelevant.

Comment: No idea how you'd make it happen in C#, but why _couldn't_ you have a regular expression engine that acts on byte strings rather then character strings?

Comment: I assume that the file doesn't contain text. It might be a dll containing string constants the OP wants to hack.

Comment: Robert: the output varies inasmuch as some byte values get changed. For example, the '03DC' in the input file gets changed to 'FDFF' in the output file (this is using Unicode encoding instead of utf8).

Comment: Dammit, rollback never works how I expect.

Comment: Justin: Regex is quite relevant because there are numerous ASCII strings that I want to find/replace.  Much easier to use regular expressions.

Comment: Olivier: even doing a ReadAllText immediately followed by a WriteAllText yields a modified output file.

Comment: Barry, how about if you read it as ASCII rather than utf8?

Comment: But you're not asking anything about *how* to use regex for this. You're trying to edit text strings embedded in a binary file. Regex isn't nearly relevant enough to be in the title, or to tag the question with it. In fact, its only relevance here is to give context.

Comment: And it doesn't work to simply convert the string supplied to Regex to a hex string :-(. Regex apparently does some magic so that when I say look for "H[a-z]" it doesn't really look for an "H" followed by a "[", but to convert the string to hex will give you exactly that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it!  Check out the code:

```
        string infile = @"C:\temp\in.dat";
        string outfile = @"C:\temp\out.dat";
        Regex re = new Regex(@"H[a-z]+ W[a-z]+");   // looking for "Hello World"
        string repl =  @"Hi there";

        Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
        byte[] inbytes = File.ReadAllBytes(infile);
        string instr = ascii.GetString(inbytes);
        Match match = re.Match(instr);
        int beg = 0;
        bool replaced = false;
        List<byte> newbytes = new List<byte>();
        while (match.Success)
        {
            replaced = true;
            for (int i = beg; i < match.Index; i++)
                newbytes.Add(inbytes[i]);
            foreach (char c in repl)
                newbytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(c));
            Match nmatch = match.NextMatch();
            int end = (nmatch.Success) ? nmatch.Index : inbytes.Length;
            for (int i = match.Index + match.Length; i < end; i++)
                newbytes.Add(inbytes[i]);
            beg = end;
            match = nmatch;
        }
        if (replaced)
        {
            var newarr = newbytes.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllBytes(outfile, newarr);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(outfile, inbytes);
        }
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. The output of this code will be `63,0,63`. `Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
    byte[] inbytes = new byte[] {255,0,255 };
    string instr = ascii.GetString(inbytes);
    var outbytes = ascii.GetBytes(instr);`

Comment: Barry, you possibly loose bytes>128.

Comment: I appreciate the warning, and I can't explain it, but my file has lots of values > 128 (e.g., 81, 9A, AE).

Comment: `I can't explain it,` Barry, Binary data is *binary*, trying to converting it to string with any encoding will result in loss of some data. I don't think this is the correct way to go. But,anyway, It is your choice.

Answer (score 2):

Not all binary strings are valid UTF-8 strings. When you try to interpret the binary as a UTF-8 string, the bytes that can't be thus interpreted are probably getting mangled. Basically, if the whole file is not encoded text, then interpreting it as encoded text will not yield sensible results.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspect that "the whole file is not encoded text".  So is there no way to read a binary file, edit some ascii strings, and write the new binary file without bytes getting mangled?

Comment: I'm sure there is. This is probably not the best way, but it might work to pick some 8-bit encoding that round-trips to arbitrary binary. It looks like Windows-1252 is not such an encoding.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to playing with binary file can be: converting it to hex string, working on it(Regex can be used here) and then saving it back

```
byte[] buf = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
var str = new SoapHexBinary(buf).ToString();

//str=89504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000000C8000000C808030000009A865EAC00000300504C544......
//Do your work

File.WriteAllBytes(file,SoapHexBinary.Parse(str).Value);
```

PS: Namespace : `System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary`